# iOS8 AlertViewController issue

Tags: ios8, uialertcontroller

I have one `textField` in my `viewController`, when `AlertViewController` is appear keyboard is not appear at in background of the AlertViewController. But After dismiss `AlertViewController` Keyboard is appear. This thing happen only for ios8 device. Here is my following Code:

```
 [textField becomeFirstResponder];

 if([self checkIfiOS8])
 {
          // for iOS 8 
          UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Your Title"
                                                                               message:@"Your message" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
          UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) { }];
          [alert addAction:cancelAction];
          [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

 }
 else
 {
           // iOS7
           UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Your Title" message:@"Your message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
           [alert show];
           [alert release];
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"AlertView" message:@"I am an AlertView" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
UIAlertAction* defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                      handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                                          [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                                                      }];
[alert addAction:defaultAction];
[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```